# Screen Recorder bug - Unexpected error while copying video recording from device: Remote object doesn't exist

Tags: android-studio

From time to time Screen Recorder can't save the video, so it's just: *"works, doesn't work, works, doesn't work and so on..."*

> Unexpected error while copying video recording from device: Remote
>   object doesn't exist!

For example when I stop video recording (pressing *stop recording* button):

[image]

it says everything is ok (Screen Recorder says that he recorded and saved your video file):

[image]

But in reality when I press any button within the popup window (*Open*, *Show in Explorer*, *OK*) the next error popup window appears:

[image]

and there is no saved video file...

Comment: I also faced the same issue I am using OPPO Real me pro 2 device have you found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Faced this issue a couple of times.

Restarting the Android Studio usually works for me.

Hope this helps!